# How to calculate a Time Zone from my server

Tags: date, timezone

My server runs on UCT time.

What is the command to check a specific time zone? i.e. America/New_York

And to be clear, I don't wish to update the servers time zone, I just want to know what it calculates another time zone to be.

Comment: Yes all Unix machines should use UTC. The timezone is applied at display time.

Comment: Are you asking “How do I show the time in another timezone?“

Comment: yes - I just want to display the time of a different time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to specify the time zone in the environment when running the `date` command:

```
$ TZ=America/New_York date
Wed Jul 17 07:16:39 EDT 2019
```

Comment: Crap, 22 seconds faster

Answer (score 1):

From `man date`:

> Show the time on the west coast of the US (use tzselect(1) to find TZ)

```
$ TZ='America/Los_Angeles' date
```

This works by setting the variable `TZ` to a new value just for the `date` command.